# Looking to find text in powerpoint and replace using text from a cell in excel using vba, but keep getting error

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

this part of my code should find text in powerpoint shapes and replace it with text from a cell in excel:

```
Dim oSld As Slide
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim oTxtRng As TextRange
Dim oTmpRng As TextRange
Dim strWhatReplace As String, strReplaceText As String

 ' write find text
strWhatReplace = "xxxxx"
 ' write change text
strReplaceText = Sheet13.Range("C1").Value


        ' go during each slides
For Each oSld In ppPres.Slides
     ' go during each shapes and textRanges
    For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
         ' replace in TextFrame
        Set oTxtRng = oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
        Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.replace( _
        FindWhat:=strWhatReplace, _
        Replacewhat:=strReplaceText, _
        WholeWords:=True)

            Do While Not oTmpRng Is Nothing 
            Set oTxtRng = oTxtRng.Characters _
            (oTmpRng.Start + oTmpRng.Length, oTxtRng.Length)
            Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.replace( _
            FindWhat:=strWhatReplace, _
            Replacewhat:=strReplaceText, _
            WholeWords:=True)
        Loop
    Next oShp
Next oSld
```

I keep getting runtime error 13, type mismatch - the debug highlights 'For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes'
Not sure where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have references to Microsoft Excel **and** Microsoft PowerPoint Object Library, then there are two types of `Shape`s.

Seems you have dimensioned `Excel.Shape` but then you get `PowerPoint.Shape`.

Try `Dim oShp As PowerPoint.Shape`.

Comment: i tried Dim OShp as PowerPoint.shape, but now my error is 'the specified value is out of range' highlighted on the line Set oTxtRng = oShp.TextFrame.TextRange

Comment: Maybe the `PowerPoint.Shape` has not a `TextFrame`? See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff743875.aspx.

Comment: Perhaps, how do I get it to search text in any shape in the powerpoint and then replace with what i want?

Comment: After your For Each oShp line, wrap the lines up to the Next oShp line inside If oShp.HasTextframe Then

Answer (score 0):

That means VBA thinks that the variable type of oShp is not the same as the type returned by oSld.Shapes. The code looks ok to me but you could type this in the Immediate window to double check when the code stops at that point:

```
?TypeName(oShp)
?TypeName(oSld.Shapes)
```

You should see that one is not of type Shape (although I can't see how when reading your code).

Where is ppPres getting declared and set? Is that of type Presentation?

Comment: ppPres is declared earlier in the code, and is a Presentation. i tried Dim OShp as PowerPoint.shape, but now my error is 'the specified value is out of range' highlighted on the line Set oTxtRng = oShp.TextFrame.TextRange

Comment: Some shapes (lines, arrows, smartart, groups) don't have a TextRange property; try putting that line inside an If oShp.HasTextFrame / End If block